# How send data from js to flask

Tags: javascript, python, flask

i have issue to send data in flask from js. I try use ajax.
[image]

AJAX code

```
      $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
        url: "/getmethod/data",
        traditional: "true",
        data: JSON.stringify({data}),
        dataType: "json"
        });
```

Python code

```
def get_javascript_data(data):

    content = request.get_data('data')
    jsonify(content)
```

If u got some tips or tricks please tell me.

Comment: i getting value, but in flask cant accept it. say data not found or something like what. delete_value?{"data":[1,"UK%20CALENDAR","Wed,%2001%20Jan%202020%2000:00:00%20GMT","Wed,%2001%20Jan%202020%2000:00:00%20GMT","A2A%20IM","hjfj","lukgfk"]}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
new_item = $('#input').val() //value I want to send 
$.ajax({ 
    url: '/set_value', 
    type: 'POST', 
    data: new_item,
    success: function(response){ 
        $('#main').text(response) 
    } 
})
```

in flask:

```
new_item = request.get_data()
```

Comment: So, in flask i must change method in post right? so how must look querty delete?

Comment: you want POST something from a form via ajax and GET this information in flask right?

Comment: yes. I want get table value then i press delete botton, and then use what value for my sql querty.

Comment: ok, but dont work for me.. idk maybe querty bad or something like what.  
`@api.route('/delete_value', methods=['GET'])`
`@login_required`
`def get_javascript_data(new_item):`
   ` new_item = request.get_data() `
   ` mycursor = conn.cursor() `
    `sql = "DELETE FROM CalEvents Where eventId = new_item[0]"`
    `cursor.execute(sql)`
    `conn.commit()`
    `return (mycursor.rowcount, "record(s) deleted")`

Comment: try to remove the " methods=['GET']" part from you flask route...

Comment: TypeError: get_javascript_data() missing 1 required positional argument: 'new_item'
and function not working.